# How to intentionally exit in playground?

Tags: swift-playground

In a playground I have a function that returns an array of values that are calculated from numbers supplied in a calling statement. The function checks the numbers to confirm they are valid and if they are not valid I output an explanatory comment and then I want to stop -- I don't want to plunge ahead and let errors occur because of the bad data. Is there a way to stop? I tried the obvious possibilities (exit(), stop(), end(), etc.) but nothing I tried is recognized.

I can think of work-arounds. What I'm asking is how to program a stop? I know that playground can stop because it stops after the last statement. If it had 'goto' I could go to a final statement, but 'goto' is not recognized either.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you might want to design this in a different way:

```
// Within your playground main file: Contents.swift
startPlayground()


// Possibly within another file in the Sources directly:
func startPlayground() {
   let input = receiveInputFromYourSource()
   guard verifyInput(input) == true else {
      showErrorMessageToUser()
      return
   }
}
```

This structure allows you to use `return` in the desired way of an "exit function". This is probably the most elegant way to achieve what you want to do. Structures like "goto" are not supported by swift and you should always look for an alternative.

Having said that, there is a special case that might be useful from time to time in Swift Playgrounds:

```
assertionFailure(message: "Input not correct")
```

This statement terminates the execution of the playground while also giving an error message.